# Colored Cygwin font

Tags: cygwin

Is there a way to enable syntax highlighting in Cygwin such as blue for directories, green for files, etc?

I would ideally use puttycyg, but I am getting a cygwin1.dll not found error, then receiving an x0000007b error when the cygwin1.dll is copied into the puttycyg folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Font colors and directory colors can be set making changes in user shell profile. So if you are using bash shell then you can make changes in .bashrc.
Check this sample here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Then you can either check/set colors in the `/etc/DIR_COLORS` file, or if you want to override those colors in `.bash_profile`, add these lines:

```
LS_COLORS="di=31;1:ln=36;1:ex=31;1:*~=31;1:*.html=31;1:*.shtml=37;1"
export LS_COLORS
```